# ¿Cómo establecer texto de Html.ActionLink en Asp.Net Mvc desde JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

¿Cómo puedo hacer para cambiar el texto de Html.ActionLink desde codigo JavaScript en Asp.Net Mvc?

tengo:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Inicio", "Index", "Home")
```

y desde codigo JavaScript quiero cambiar el texto que se muestra...algo asi:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un `@Html.ActionLink` lo que te genera en una vez entregada la vista en un *html anchor tag*, al cual le puede poner un id o clase para poderlo referenciar desde javascript. La sintaxis a seguir para poner un id sería:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Inicio", "Index", "Home", null, new { id = "tu_id" })
```

lo cual genere un html del tipo:

```
<a href="/" id="tu_id">Inicio</a>
```

Con esto, ya podrás utilizar jquery, por ejemplo, para manipular cualquier de sus propiedades

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tu_id").text("Home");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Una vez que tu vista ya cargo no es posible cambiar un **Helper**, ya que un `@Html.ActionLink`, `Razor` lo transforma a un `<a href""></a>`

Lo que podrias hacer es cambiar el `href` de tu `a`

```
$("a").attr("href", "/Home/Index");
```

Comment: este codigo agrega jQuery